# How to build a module for kernel linux to calculate and show seconds and jiffies?

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system

I have a simple code:

```
/**
 * simple.c
 * A simple kernel module. 
 * To compile, run makefile by entering "make"
 */

#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>

/* This function is called when the module is loaded. */
int simple_init(void)
{
       printk(KERN_INFO "Loading Module\n");

       return 0;
}

/* This function is called when the module is removed. */
void simple_exit(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Removing Module\n");
}

/* Macros for registering module entry and exit points. */
module_init( simple_init );
module_exit( simple_exit );

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("Simple Module");
MODULE_AUTHOR("SGG");
```

and this:

```
obj-m += simple.o
all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

I want to build a module for kernel Linux to calculate and show seconds and jiffies then with command cat/proc, print result.
how can I?

Comment: Is the code so far not working? What is not clear? What do you mean by "calculate" exactly? Why does this have to do with `cat` and `proc`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.